# Get status of TTS

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Is there a way to have sth like a listener which works when the TTS is working ? So when the speak function is called and the device is talking until it finishs. I found out that theres a OnUtteranceCompletedListener which shows you that it finished. But I need it when the TTS is still active. Some Ideas ?

Comment: Since API 15 there is [UtteranceProgressListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html). API 4-18 (deprecated, then) there is [OnUtteranceCompletedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html).

Comment: but this OnUtteranceCompletedListener only gives the end Im right ? I need it also for lower than API 15. So  UtteranceProgressListener is invalid for me

Comment: Yes, right: `Listener that will be called when the TTS service has completed synthesizing an utterance.`

Answer (score 0):

You can check [UtteranceProgressListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html). Between the `onStart` and the `onDone` call, the TTS should be active. There should be some error cases treated in the `onError` methods also.

Comment: But this is for API 15+ . I need sth like that for lower than 15.